# Help choose correct HDMI GPU resolution to get standard PAL/NTSC signal

Tags: video-standards, formats

Hi im trying to go from computer's ATI GPU via hdmi->component_adapter to [SD DVB-T Modulator](http://www.shputech.com/news.php?module=product&act=show&classid=18&id=141).

According to modulator spec it does 720x576_50i (PAL) & 720x480_60i (NTSC)

Which if any of these control panel resolution choices would match either or those: (ive reduced the list to the ones i think are closest)

- 720 by 576 (16bit) 50 Hertz
- 720 by 576 (16bit) 25 Hertz (Interlaced)
- 720 by 480 (16bit) 60 Hertz
- 720 by 480 (16bit) 30 Hertz (Interlaced)

And finally how would any of these compare to the outputs from a [Decklink Mini Monitor](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/au/products/decklink/techspecs/W-DLK-05), that states it does SD 625/25 PAL, 525/29.97 NTSC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of your list, these look like your acceptable modes

> 720 by 576 (16bit) 25 Hertz (Interlaced)
>
> 720 by 480 (16bit) 30 Hertz (Interlaced)

Although depending on your adapter, it may be able to work with the other two as well. Note that all the modes are 16-bit so you are working with much reduced color resolution.

The Decklink modes are PAL and NTSC spec signal outputs and, I suspect, it will automatically downscale and crop your full resolution HDMI feed, so no need to tinker with your computer display modes.

Comment: Interesting comment about the bmd rez, as now you mention it, it likely does do it internally. I can do 32bit color, just only listed 16bit for simplicity. So i did try the first one you recommended (Pal 25i)  and half the tv had the image and then it went to garble. so not sure if its the gpu not putting out a spec signal or the adapter.

Comment: Can you comment on how you think the two options you recommended would likely compare against PAL/NTSC spec signals ? , my modulator is fussy ...

Comment: Will need to know your adapter details (model #) to see how it does the conversion. Unlikely to be the GPU.

Comment: Adapter reports as Lontium, it is chinese no model. Does Hdmi in, and component YPbPr w spdif sound out or vga out. Im thinkingi will send it back, and get a used ati radeon 3450 off ebay for $20 which has YPbPr out.

Comment: Hey, it must have been the adapter, as the ati works fine with the modulator and tv when it defaults to 720 by 576 (32bit) 25 Hertz (Interlaced) for the component out. thanks